# Cannot read undefined property error - building object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am taking an online JavaScript class and am stuck on a problem involving objects. In the following code, my assignment is to output a string that retrieves the name of each ranger (e.g. lighthouseRock.ranger1.name) and match their station to the corresponding item in the superBlinders array.

If I hard-code the ranger1 property, the output format is in the right ballpark. However, if I try to be creative and build a variable (thisRanger) to dynamically insert the appropriate ranger into my object, the routine returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". My thisRanger variable builds OK but whenever I try to insert it into my chain after lightHouseRock it causes the undefined problem. Here is my code:

```
var superBlinders = [ ["Firestorm", 4000], ["Solar Death Ray", 6000], ["Supernova", 12000] ];
var lighthouseRock = {
  gateClosed: true,
  weaponBulbs: superBlinders,
  capacity: 30,
  secretPassageTo: "Underwater Outpost",
  numRangers: 0
};
function addRanger(location, name, skillz, station) {
  location.numRangers++;
  location["ranger" + location.numRangers] = {
    name: name, 
    skillz: skillz, 
    station: station
  };
}
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Nick Walsh", "magnification burn", 2);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Drew Barontini", "uppercut launch", 3);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Christine Wong", "bomb defusing", 1);

var dontPanic = function () {
  var message = "Avast, me hearties!\n";
  message += "There be Pirates nearby! Stations!\n";
  for (var i = 1; i <= lighthouseRock.numRangers; i++) {
    var thisRangerNumber = i;
    var thisRanger = "ranger" + thisRangerNumber;
    // message += lighthouseRock.ranger1.name + ", man the " + superBlinders[lighthouseRock.ranger1.station][0] + "!\n";
    message += lighthouseRock.thisRanger.name + ", man the " + superBlinders[lighthouseRock.thisRanger.station][0];
  };
  console.log(message);
}
```

The expected output should look something like this:

```
Avast, me hearties!
There be Pirates nearby! Stations!
<name>, man the <superblinder>!
<name>, man the <superblinder>!
<name>, man the <superblinder>!
```

How can I insert thisRanger into my code so that it gives me the expected output? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: if the answer was what you were looking for please accept it by pressing the tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code! 
It outputs all you want it todo!

**UPDATE you have an error in your code** I fixed that also..

Ranger2 will always be stationed on **undefined** since there aren't **3 stations when counting as an array**, remember array in javascript starts counting from 0(zero). I changed Drew barontini to "0"

```
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Nick Walsh", "magnification burn", 2);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Drew Barontini", "uppercut launch", 0);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Christine Wong", "bomb defusing", 1);
```

CODE OUTPUT

*Avast, me hearties!

There be Pirates nearby!
 Stations!

Nick Walsh, man the Supernova,12000 
 Drew Barontini, man the Firestorm,4000
Christine Wong, man the Solar Death Ray,6000*

I didn't do much to change your code. But what I did is that I change your code into

```
 message += lighthouseRock[thisRanger].name + ", man the " + superBlinders[lighthouseRock[thisRanger].station] +"\n";
```

Its important to know with javascript that you can use brackets [] to get to an object property if you build the stirng dynamicly.

```
var superBlinders = [ ["Firestorm", 4000], ["Solar Death Ray", 6000], ["Supernova", 12000] ];

var lighthouseRock = {
  gateClosed: true,
  weaponBulbs: superBlinders,
  capacity: 30,
  secretPassageTo: "Underwater Outpost",
  numRangers: 0
};
function addRanger(location, name, skillz, station) {
  location.numRangers++;
  location["ranger" + location.numRangers] = {
    name: name, 
    skillz: skillz, 
    station: station
  };
}
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Nick Walsh", "magnification burn", 2);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Drew Barontini", "uppercut launch", 0);
addRanger(lighthouseRock, "Christine Wong", "bomb defusing", 1);

var dontPanic = function () {
  var message = "Avast, me hearties!\n";
  message += "There be Pirates nearby! Stations!\n";
  for (var i = 1; i <= lighthouseRock.numRangers; i++) {
    var thisRangerNumber = i;
    var thisRanger = "ranger" + thisRangerNumber;
    // message += lighthouseRock.ranger1.name + ", man the " + superBlinders[lighthouseRock.ranger1.station][0] + "!\n";
    message += lighthouseRock[thisRanger].name + ", man the " + superBlinders[lighthouseRock[thisRanger].station] +"\n";
  };
  console.log(message);


}

dontPanic();
```

Comment: Awesome that does work and thank you for the clear explanations!! I do have one question: Suppose I could not change the addRanger station values. How might I account for that in the loop where I build the message variable? I tried ["ranger" + i - 1] and got undefined.

Comment: I have another potentially dumb question, but how can I access just the first half of each nested array item from the superBlinders array? For instance, I just want the retrieved content from the first item to be Firestorm and not "Firestorm", 4000. Does that make sense? I tried superBlinders[lighthouseRock["ranger" + i].station][0] but got undefined.

Comment: Post a new question and I can help you hard to answer questions in the  comment section.